# error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant from initializing a structure of known size this is C

Tags: c

This is C,(lex driver code)   straight from Schreiner and Friedman compiler book page33  just typed it in and it throws the error:

> "error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant.

Checked  and this the same bit of code with different names as per K&R  page 124 structure array initialization. There it clearly states the size of this IS known at compile time. Is this a problem with gcc? 
I am compiling off the command line as: lex samplec.l; then, cc -DDEBUG lex.yy.c -ll -o lexc ;
at which point it throws the error.
OBB

```
%{
/*
**
**  samplec.l -- lexical analysia
**
*/

#ifdef      DEBUG

#  include <assert.h>

  main ()
    {
     char * p;

     assert(sizeof(int) >= sizeof(char *));

     while (p = (char *) yylex())
       printf("%-10.10s is \"%s\"\n",p, yytext);
  }

  s_lookup() {}

  int yyerrs = 0;

#   define token(x) (int) "x"

#else ! DEBUG

#   define "y.tab.h"
#   define token(x) x

#endif DEBUG

#define END(v) (v-1 + sizeof v / sizeof v[0])
static int screen();
%}

letter                      [a-zA-Z]
digit                       [0-9]
letter_or_digit             [a-zA-Z0-9]
white_space         [ \t\n]
blank                       [ \t]
other                       .

%%

^"#"{blank}*{digit}+({blank}+.*)?\n yymark();

">="                    return token(GE);
"<="                        return token(LE);
"=="                        return token(EQ);
"!="                        return token(NE);
"+="                        return token(PE);
"-="                        return token(ME);
"*="                        return token(TE);
"/="                        return token(DE);
"%="                        return token(RE);
"++"                        return token(PP);
"--"                        return token(MM);

{letter}{letter_or_digit} return screen();

{digit}+            { s_lookup(token(Constant));
                          return token(Constant);
                    }

{white_space}*              ;

{other}                     return token(yytext[0]);

%%

/*
**
**  reserve word screening
**
*/

static struct rwtable {
    char *rw_name;
    int rw_yylex;
   } rwtable[] ={
   "break", token(BREAK),
   "continue", token(CONTINUE),
   "else", token(ELSE),
   "if", token(IF),
   "int", token(INT),
   "return", token(RETURN),
   "while", token(WHILE)
   };

static int screen()
   {
    struct rwtable * low = rwtable,
            * high = END(rwtable),
            * mid;

    int c;

    while (low <= high)
      {
       mid = low + (high-low)/2;
       if ((c = strcmp(mid->rw_name, yytext)) == 0)
            return mid->rw_yylex;
       else if (c < 0)
            low = mid+1;
       else
            high = mid-1;
     }
     s_lookup(token(Identifier));
     return token(Identifier);
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve] - the complete is what is missing here.

Comment: Is `token` a function?

Comment: You lack one intialisation hierarchy, i.e. some pairs of `{}`. Please, double check whether you really copied the book letter by letter.

Comment: What's the definition of `token`?

Comment: The MCVE requested by @AnttiHaapala will of course not be compilable. In this case "verifiable" means, that it gets exactly and only the error your are asking about.

Comment: Casting a pointer to an `int` and back to a pointer will not work if an `int` is 32 bits and a pointer is 64 bits.

Comment: The question relates to that specific bit of code.  In answer to what is token  it is defined within lex.                                                  A token is a regular expression understood by a lexical analyzer generator such as lex. The lexical analyzer (generated automatically by  lex, reads in a stream of characters, identifies the lexemes in the stream, and categorizes them into tokens. So "token" contains the next lexem to be processed.

Comment: You still didn't tell or show us, what `token` is. Is it a function or a macro that is replaced by constant expression? I would guess the first....

Comment: BTW: C does not have regular expressions.

Comment: token is: # define  token (x)  (int)  "x" , char cast to int with -DDBUG set. action is  with input  "<="  it returns token(LE);

Comment: token is as per the code: # define  token (x)  (int)  "x" ,  a  char cast to int with -DDBUG set.  Its action is  with input  "<="  it returns token(LE); some for other leximes defined from line 50 to 60 of the code I sent.  But this is not related to my question which  is still:   why  gcc thinks the rwtable[] size is not known at compile time. OBB

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is the size of `rwtable` and not the values of the initialisers? Casting an address to an `int` is not valid in a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

The book **Introduction to Compiler Construction With Unix** by *D. Friedman Schreiner, H. George Friedman Jr.* is quite dated (1985): the dialect of C it uses is no longer spoken by modern compilers.

The definition of `token` uses an obsolete form of stringification:

```
#define token(x) (int) "x"
```

This has been deprecated a long time ago, before ANSI-C.

You could try changing this definition to

```
#define token(x) #x
```

But the code relies on some other assumptions that may fail on your current system:

- `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(char*)`  -> not true on most current 64-bit systems

I suggest you look for a more up to date tutorial on compiler construction: you can find many good references online, and a lot of open source software.

Comment: That's not an obsolete form of stringification.  Lex requires the tokens to be `int`s, so the code is casting the string addresses into `int`s.  This is done so that the debug code can print the token name by casting the `int` back to a pointer.

Comment: The "real" problem is to find a compiler to compile K&R C. The aim is to try to produce one.  I was and am concerned that my original question was being side tracked by the Lex component hence my original code snippet was short and sweet.  Thanks everyone for their input.  OBB

Comment: @pat: I'm afraid you misread the macro: `#define token(x) (int) "x"` is an obsolete form of stringification. `token(GE)` used to expand to `(int) "GE"` with the original K&R C compiler, which indeed the debug code will print as a string by casting it back to `(char *)`.  Today, all conforming C compilers would expand it to `(int) "x"` which defeats the original purpose.

Comment: @pat of course it is obsolete form; if not, then the implementation is allowed to merge the strings `"x"` and all of the tokens would have the *same* value.

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you mean.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pointers are being cast to `int`.  More than likely, your pointers are 64 bits, but your `int`s are only 32 bits.  The linker has no way to represent a truncated pointer, so these values are not compile time constants.  Furthermore, if the compiler were able to represent these truncated pointers, you would get a nasty surprise when you tried casting the `int` back to a pointer, since it will likely not recover the missing 32 bits correctly.

Some platforms provide the types `intptr_t`, and `uintptr_t`, which are signed and unsigned integer types which are guaranteed to be wide enough to allow casting to and from pointer types without loss.  Of course, this doesn't help here because lex wants a plain old `int`.

Comment: Lex is not limited to `int`, but that is a total red herring since the type of a member of that struct  is not determined by lex. (The cast could be done at runtime.) And casting to  a wider integer type is still not a constant expression.

Comment: The type of the member of that struct must match the return type of `yylex`,  since the purpose of the table is to convert reserved words that look like identifiers into token numbers.  I never said that casting to a wider type was a constant expression, I merely introduced `uintptr_t` to drive home the fact that `int` and pointer are not guaranteed to be the same width.

Comment: You said "... so these values are not compile time constants" which implies that if they were not truncated, they would be. That's misleading IMHO. It would be valid to store `const char*` in the table and cast to `uintptr_t` at run time; that would make more sense if `YYSTYPE` were `uintptr_t`, of course, but the point I was making was about the type of the struct member, which doesn't have to be the same as the type returned by the function. (And even better would be to use a `%union` to avoid a cast altogether.)

Comment: Well yes, it would be better if the associated data we're stored in `yylval`, but that's not the case here.  The code is attempting to use string addresses as token *numbers*, not as token *values*.

Comment: On further investigation yes the char * is bigger than an int. So i have cast it to a long and replaced ints all over with longs. The original error is now gone thank you all for help and suggestions.  But other difficulties remain which I will attempt to fix myself first. OBB.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because an initializer of an object of *static storage duration* must be a constant; and according to [C11 6.6p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p6):

> *An integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall **only** have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer constants, _Alignof expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. **Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types**, except as part of an operand to the sizeof or _Alignof operator.

`"x"` has the type `char *`, pointers are not arithmetic types, and thus the pointer cast to an integer cannot be an integer constant  expression.

Comment: And how to solve it? You mention C11, but it's easy to access older dialects: for instance, on macOS, you can pass `-std=c99` or `-std=c89`. Would that help to solve the problem?

Comment: Of course it would do absolutely nothing at all to fix this problem. This program is an ugly hack and the code must be fixed, not the compiler switches.